# background image fit on the div width and height with bootstrap columns - PARALLAX

Tags: html, css, background-image, parallax

I have a div with different background-images and must be a parallax but the background-image is always in 100% and connects in the width of the body.

Here's the code:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6" style="padding: .2em;">
   <div class="type-card" style="background-image: url(https://d4kkpd69xt9l7.cloudfront.net/sys-master/images/h70/h02/9215436357662/razer-viper-B-950x580-desktop.jpg);">

  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6" style="padding: .2em;">
  <div class="type-card" style="background-image:url(https://d4kkpd69xt9l7.cloudfront.net/sys-master/images/h10/hc4/9211330592798/Lynette-Core-Promo-B-954x580-desktop.jpg);">

  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6" style="padding: .2em;">
  <div class="type-card" style="background-image:url(https://d4kkpd69xt9l7.cloudfront.net/sys-master/images/h36/h37/9201084170270/BTS-Zone-B-954x580-desktop.jpg)">

  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6" style="padding: .2em;">
  <div class="type-card" style="background-image:url(https://d4kkpd69xt9l7.cloudfront.net/sys-master/images/h0f/hc7/9211330658334/Silver-Store-Promo-B-954x580-desktop.jpg)">

  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6" style="padding: .2em;">
  <div class="type-card" style="background-image:url(https://d4kkpd69xt9l7.cloudfront.net/sys-master/images/h90/hc7/9193016623134/razer-kraken-x-B-950x580-desktop.jpg)">

  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6" style="padding: .2em;">
  <div class="type-card" style="background-image:url(https://d4kkpd69xt9l7.cloudfront.net/sys-master/images/hd5/h3b/9185281343518/razer-insider-B-950x580-desktop.jpg)">

  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6" style="padding: .2em;">
  <div class="type-card" style="background-image: url(https://media.steelseriescdn.com/thumbs/filer_public/cb/43/cb43b953-4b2f-4c35-8a77-01964ca5717a/fronttile_apexpro_001.jpg__1920x600_q100_crop-scale_optimize_subsampling-2.jpg);">

  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6" style="padding: .2em;">
  <div class="type-card" style="background-image: url(https://media.steelseriescdn.com/thumbs/filer_public/bc/91/bc91a8cc-a2df-40d4-9354-a42f37bcb82d/r650_front_page_001.jpg__1920x600_q100_crop-scale_optimize_subsampling-2.jpg);">

  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I want to fit the background image in the width and height of the div. Please help me out of this problem, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

added below css

```
.type-card{
    height: 250px;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;}
```

```css
.type-card{
    height: 250px;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6" style="padding: .2em;">
    <div class="type-card" style="background-image: url(https://d4kkpd69xt9l7.cloudfront.net/sys-master/images/h70/h02/9215436357662/razer-viper-B-950x580-desktop.jpg);">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6" style="padding: .2em;">
    <div class="type-card" style="background-image:url(https://d4kkpd69xt9l7.cloudfront.net/sys-master/images/h10/hc4/9211330592798/Lynette-Core-Promo-B-954x580-desktop.jpg);">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6" style="padding: .2em;">
    <div class="type-card" style="background-image:url(https://d4kkpd69xt9l7.cloudfront.net/sys-master/images/h36/h37/9201084170270/BTS-Zone-B-954x580-desktop.jpg)">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6" style="padding: .2em;">
    <div class="type-card" style="background-image:url(https://d4kkpd69xt9l7.cloudfront.net/sys-master/images/h0f/hc7/9211330658334/Silver-Store-Promo-B-954x580-desktop.jpg)">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6" style="padding: .2em;">
    <div class="type-card" style="background-image:url(https://d4kkpd69xt9l7.cloudfront.net/sys-master/images/h90/hc7/9193016623134/razer-kraken-x-B-950x580-desktop.jpg)">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6" style="padding: .2em;">
    <div class="type-card" style="background-image:url(https://d4kkpd69xt9l7.cloudfront.net/sys-master/images/hd5/h3b/9185281343518/razer-insider-B-950x580-desktop.jpg)">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6" style="padding: .2em;">
    <div class="type-card" style="background-image: url(https://media.steelseriescdn.com/thumbs/filer_public/cb/43/cb43b953-4b2f-4c35-8a77-01964ca5717a/fronttile_apexpro_001.jpg__1920x600_q100_crop-scale_optimize_subsampling-2.jpg);">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6" style="padding: .2em;">
    <div class="type-card" style="background-image: url(https://media.steelseriescdn.com/thumbs/filer_public/bc/91/bc91a8cc-a2df-40d4-9354-a42f37bcb82d/r650_front_page_001.jpg__1920x600_q100_crop-scale_optimize_subsampling-2.jpg);">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you xenio, but the problem is parallax is working in 2 columns? thank you. :D

Comment: hi, I didnt get you.

Comment: the parallax that you give to me is working in full width `100%` and the background image is 100% too, but I want to 100% the background image in 2 columns, but the out put is the background image is 100% but the div is only 50% width.

Comment: but you gave `col-md-6` class which will display div with 50% width.